# Construction of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, operator-theory, special-functions, spectral-theory, spectral-sequences

Can I find a sequence $(f_j)_{j\in\Bbb{N}}\in  C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R^+})$ such that : $$
 \lim_{j\to\infty}\int^\infty_0 \big(\partial^2_r  f_j+\frac{1}{r}\partial_r f_j+r^2f_j\big)^2 rdr=0$$  and $$ \sqrt{\int_{\Bbb{R^+}}|f_j(r)|^2 rdr}=1 $$ .

Thank you for any suggestion whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

There are many sequences verifying the conditions. Assuming, for example,
\begin{equation}
f_j=a_je^{-k_jr^2}
\end{equation} 
with $\Re k_j>0$, one has
\begin{equation}
F_j(r)=f''_j(r)+\frac{1}{r}f'_j(r)+r^2f_j(r)=a_j\left(r^2\left( 1+4k_j^2 \right)-4k_j \right)
\end{equation} 
and thus
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\left[F_j(r)\right]^2r\,dr=\frac{a_j^2}{8k_j^3}\left( 16k_j^4+1 \right)
\end{equation} 
One can choose the condition
\begin{equation}
k_j^4\to -\frac{1}{16} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation} 
for $j\to\infty$. 
Also, if $k_j=u_j+iv_j$, with $u_j>0$ and $v_j\in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation}
\left|f_j(r)\right|^2=\left|a_j\right|^2e^{-2u_jr^2}
\end{equation} 
We deduce
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\left|f_j(r)\right|^2r\,dr=\frac{\left|a_j\right|^2}{4u_j}
\end{equation} 
The condition reads 
$$\left|a_j\right|^2=4u_j \tag{2}\label{2}$$ 
Both conditions \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} are satisfied if we choose, for example,
\begin{align}
k_j&=\frac{1+i(1+1/j)}{2\sqrt{2}}\\
a_j&=2^{\frac{1}{4}}
\end{align}
obtaining thus 
\begin{equation}
f_j(r)=2^{\tfrac 1 4}\exp\left(-\tfrac{1+i\left( 1+\frac{1}{j} \right)}{2\sqrt{2}}r^2\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: I have another question: if we use the same notation can we find a sequence $(f_j)\in C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R}$ such that $$ \lim_{j\to\infty}\int_0^\infty |F_j(r)(r)|^2 rdr= 0$$. If I adapt your approach I get $$\int_0^\infty |F_j(r)(r)|^2 rdr= \frac{1 - 8 v_j^2 + 16 (u_j^2 + v_j^2)^2 }{u_j^2} = \frac{(1-4(u_j^2+v_j^2))^2 + 8
 u_j^2}{u_j^2} \geq \frac{ 8 u_j^2}{u_j^2} = 8 $$. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately for such a simple form I think it is not possible. Imposing a new condition may require to add a "degree of freedom" for the function. May be a form like $(a+br^2)\exp(-kr^2)$ may do the job, but the calculations become more tedious.

Comment: With $br^2\exp(kr^2)$ it is not possible, I try now with $(a+br^2)\exp(kr^2)$. I think there is no such sequence.

Comment: For $a_j r^3\exp(-k_jr^2)$ I find the following condition $$\lim_{j\to\infty} \dfrac{1712u^{\frac{9}{2}}-16320u^{\frac{5}{2}}v^2-16u^{\frac{7}{2}} -1920u^{\frac{5}{2}}-1920\sqrt{u}v^2+15\sqrt{2\pi} u^4+105 \sqrt{2\pi}u^2v^2                     }{u^{\frac{5}{2}}}=0$$

where $u=(u_j)$ and $v=(v_j)$. Is it possible to find such $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @ Paul Enta Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645730/finding-a-condition-on-x-j-y-j-s-j-t-j-u-j-v-j-so-that